# Query order by specific number and after, do ordering by ascending

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Table **subject**:

```
+--------+----+
|  name  | id |
+--------|----+
| apple  | 3  |
| banana | 1  |
| tree   | 4  |
| horse  | 6  |
| bird   | 7  |
| raq    | 2  |
+--------+----+
```

So I try to have an ouput like that (if, for example, my `$id_subject = 4`, my next row MUST be 5 -6 7-1....)

```
+--------+----+
|  name  | id |
+--------+----+
| tree   | 4  |
| horse  | 6  |
| bird   | 7  |
| banana | 1  |
| raq    | 2  |
| apple  | 3  |
+--------+----+
```

My query:

```
select subject_url,subjects.id
    from students_group
    left join teacher_group on teacher_group.group_school_id = students_group.group_id
    left join subjects on teacher_group.subject_id = subjects.id
    where   students_group.user_id = 83
    ORDER BY subjects.id = 5 desc
```

But I got this output:

```
+--------+----+
|  name  | id |
+--------+----+
| tree   | 4  |
| apple  | 3  |
| banana | 1  |
| horse  | 6  |
| bird   | 7  |
| raq    | 2  |
+--------+----+
```

How can I make it work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORDER BY 
if (subjects.id=$id_subject, -1,
  if (subjects.id>$id_subject, 0, 1)
), subjects.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

ORDER BY subjects.id >= 5 desc, subjects.id asc

"subjects.id >= 5" will return 1 or 0, so the rows for which is true will come first, and among  those rows, they will be ordered ascending by id

Answer (score 0):

```
select subject_url,subjects.id
from students_group
left join teacher_group on teacher_group.group_school_id = students_group.group_id
left join subjects on teacher_group.subject_id = subjects.id
where   students_group.user_id = 83
ORDER BY 
     (subjects.id >= 4) DESC
   ,  subjects.id       ASC
```